# Node.js for loop output only last item from JSON

Tags: node.js, for-loop

The code below only output the last result, I don't get it. I check if the updateDate item contains 2020-05 both items does and I get only the last one. The loop is not looping :)

```
const briefing = [
        {
          "updateDate": "2020-05-05T00:00:00.0Z",
        },
        {
          "updateDate": "2020-05-06T00:00:00.0Z",
         },
         {
         "updateDate": "2020-05-13T00:00:00.0Z",
        }
        ];

       let date = new Date();
        var formattedYearMonth = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-';

        for (var i = 0; i < briefing.length; i++) {
            var jsonDate = briefing[i].updateDate;
            if (jsonDate.includes(formattedYearMonth)) {
            var response = JSON.stringify(briefing[i]);
            }
        }return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < briefing.length; i++) {
            var jsonDate = briefing[i].updateDate;
            if (jsonDate.includes(formattedYearMonth)) {
               var response = JSON.stringify(briefing[i]); // <==== THIS IS WHERE YOUR PROBLEM LIES
            }
        }return response;
```

The loop is actually looping :). But for every run of the loop, you are resetting the value of `response`.

--EDITED--

For the response to be an array, you need to modify your code as

```
let response = [];
for (var i = 0; i < briefing.length; i++) {
    var jsonDate = briefing[i].updateDate;
    if (jsonDate.includes(formattedYearMonth)) {
        response.push(JSON.stringify(briefing[i])); 
    }
}
return response;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your expertise. Mmm OK, so how do I get all the results then. Any idea? I am really stuck here.

Comment: Depends on how you need to send it in the response. If you need to send it as a string or an array.

Comment: Thanks, Rachit. As an array that I can format as a JSON output using stringify.

Comment: Edited my response.

Comment: It works, but moreover, it makes sense to me now. I was missing the push but also the response needed to be outside of the loop. Thank you Rachit, it helped a lot to understand my mistakes.